# How can I delete Topics using confluent-kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka to make multiple micro services communicate with each other. Services are written in Python, and I use Confluent library to handle Kafka.
At some point, I know that some Topics are just 'over', so that I could clean them automatically.

Is there a way to delete "Topics" thanks to Confluent library ? I cannot find any documentation on this...

Thanks

Comment: I'm intrigued, why would a topic be finished with? Unless the service itself is being destroyed? AFAIK you can't manage topics from the Python client, you'd use the Kafka admin client instead. Typically topics are created/deleted as an admin/ops function, not as part of an application and client library.

Comment: I might use it in a wrong way, so... The topics in question are Streaming topics, containing series of events, feeded by different clients. Once the "story" ends, the content is stored appart in the DB. Then the Topic has no real interest. It can be deleted. I can wait for the KAFKA garbage collection though, to do the job.

Comment: I also thought about using a specific Broker for these story Topics, with a configuration which makes assumes that the lifetime of the Topics are "short".

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [confluent Admin Api's to delete a topic](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html?highlight=admin#confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient.delete_topics)

**Example**

Takes an AdminClient instance and a list of topics

```
def example_delete_topics(a, topics):
    """ delete topics """

    # Call delete_topics to asynchronously delete topics, a future is returned.
    # By default this operation on the broker returns immediately while
    # topics are deleted in the background. But here we give it some time (30s)
    # to propagate in the cluster before returning.
    #
    # Returns a dict of <topic,future>.
    fs = a.delete_topics(topics, operation_timeout=30)

    # Wait for operation to finish.
    for topic, f in fs.items():
        try:
            f.result()  # The result itself is None
            print("Topic {} deleted".format(topic))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to delete topic {}: {}".format(topic, e))
```

Comment: the above example is using confluent-kafka lib not kafka-python

Comment: confluent-kafka-python is what was requested AKA confluent-kafka https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python

Answer (score 1):

<strike>To answer your question literally : no, AFAIK you can't delete topics using the client library.</strike>

This is possible using the [AdminClient API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52385333/2308683)

To address some of your follow up questions, I would suggest there is no point deleting these topics. If you're running a sandbox/prototype, then maybe you end up with lots of topics you want to clear down from experimenting. But once you move these microservices into a Production environment, each topic will serve a purpose, and perhaps it's finished processing the *current* set of data, but what about the *next*? Unless you're doing something funky with your topic naming that ties it to some attributes in the data, then topics will be re-used.

Comment: About your comment, indeed, I use a convention where the topic are the story 'identifier', let's say. I allows me create clients, (=groups), that follows the content of the story when they want. It makes easy to follow the story, without filtering out some 'key' in a general Topic named 'All Story'. Do you feel there is a limitation I am missing somewhere, in the way to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest example:

```
from kafka import KafkaAdminClient


admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:port'])
admin_client.delete_topics(topics=['test1', 'test2'])
```

Doc: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient.delete_topics

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple Python function:

```
def delete_kafka_topic(topic_name):
    call(["/usr/bin/kafka-topics", "--zookeeper", "zookeeper-1:2181", "--delete", "--topic", topic_name])
```

My team uses this in automated tests, where we want to be able to rerun tests, verify results, and not see results from previous test attempts.

Comment: Using the built-in Admin API doesn't require Kafka scripts to be available on the host

Comment: The existence of that Admin API post-dates my answer :) I am voting for your newer answer.